# spring-data-cassandra how to implement generic repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-cassandra

I'm familiar with Spring Data Repositories concept, but what should I do when I need standard CRUD for 100 different models? Creating 100 Repository classes doesn't look like good solution especially when all what I need is regular CRUD, without any specific operations.

Please, let me know if you know how better handle that in Spring Data Cassandra. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Vladimir,

having 100 domain classes in one single application might be an indicator to split up things a bit. Spring Data Repositories always require an interface to create a repository instance. IMHO, you have two possibilities:

1. Use `CassandraOperations` for CRUD operations where you do not require specialized query methods to look items up by properties other than the primary key.
2. Create a *own* repository implementation based either on an existing `Repository` interface or own interfaces where you basically provide the features you need. While booting your container, register bean definitions to create instances of the repositories. This clearly removes the advantage of custom query methods but gives more type safety than using just `CassandraOperations`.

Maybe a mix of both possibilities is suitable for your case.

HTH, Mark